# MySQL and JApplet (yes another one)

Tags: java, mysql, applet

Before I begin I would like to mention that I have researched this thoroughly and have yet to find a solution which has worked for me (a good 2-3 days of research).

Currently using :
WAMPServer Version 2.1 (Apache service disabled)
Eclipse-jee x64
javac 1.6.0_22
Windows 7 x64

The applet, webpage, and database are all residing on my local computer.

First and foremost my applet works without issues in the Eclipse IDE, however I am constantly recieving the following error when attempting to run it as applet.html with the following script:

```
<applet code="GUI.class"
    name="Some name goes here"
    archive="APTracker.jar"
    width="1000" height="700">
    Your browser is not Java enabled.
</applet>
```

1. I have exported my class files using Eclipse IDE which has included the manifest into appletJar.jar.
2. The Jar exported by Eclipse does NOT contain the mysql-connector library
3. After assembling my class files I manually extracted the `com` and `org` files from the mysql-connector jar and
   input them into my appletJar.jar
4. Following this I signed my applet jar (and confirmed it is signed) with a key which expires in 6 months.

After these steps I still receive the error message shown below.

I have tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 which did not work. I have also tried placing the mysql-connector.jar
in the jre, jdk, and root class files which showed no change.

```
    private final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javadb";
    private final String USERNAME = "xxxxxx";
    private final String PASSWORD = "xxxxxx";

    private Connection connection = null;
    private PreparedStatement selectAllAirports = null;

    private ResultSet resultSet;
    private ResultSetMetaData metaData;

    /* Establish PreparedStatements */
    public ResultSetTableModel()
    {
        try
        {   
            //establish connection to database
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            //load driver class
            Class.forName( DRIVER );

            //create prepared statements
            selectAllAirports = connection.prepareStatement( "SELECT asciiname, latitude, longitude, elevation, timezone, country_code FROM geoname;" );
        }
        catch ( SQLException sqlException )
        {
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
            //System.exit(1);
        }
        catch ( ClassNotFoundException classNotFound )
        {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException triggered.");
            classNotFound.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the error message which I receive:

```
C:\Users\Mr.\Desktop\Applet>appletviewer applet.html
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javadb
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
        at ResultSetTableModel.(ResultSetTableModel.java:38)
        at GUI.(GUI.java:20)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:785)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:714)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:368)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
        at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)
        at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:277)
        at GUI.init(GUI.java:60)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:424)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: +1 for actually searching first *and* writing a good explanation of your problem.

Comment: You can try: archive="APTracker.jar,mysqlDriver.jar"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that recent JDBC drivers don't need the `Class.forName()` call **if** the service loader method is supported.

The current Connector/J version **does** support that, **but** by including only the `org` and `com` directories of the JDBC driver you "broke" it: The service loader mechanism depends on files under the `META-INF` directory.

So with your setup you would *indeed* need the `Class.forName()` call. But in your code that code is **after** the attempt to get the connection, which won't do any good.

So do one of those:

- Add the relevant service files from the JDBC driver (under `META-INF/services`) to your jar file (and get rid of the unnecessary `Class.forName()` call) or
- Put the `Class.forName()` call **before** the  `DriverManager.getConnection()` call.

Comment: Superb explanation, and after following the second step I was able to compact the entire applet into a single JAR & html file. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to manually put the MySQL class files into your APTracker.jar, why not just include the MySQL jar on the applet's classpath?

I suspect there is something in the MySQL jar file's META-INF directory that you need - a ServiceLoader configuration file or some such.

Comment: Probably because his jar file is signed and you can't mix signed and unsigned classes in an applet.

Comment: Yeah, but he could always sign the MySQL jar file.

Comment: I am not sure why I didn't try this before. Signed the Driver jar, included it and now works like a charm thank you 
so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Things to consider are:

1. Do you have `mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar` or any related connector in your machine? If none, ask it in google?
2. If you have, paste the connector at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk...\jre\lib\ext` directory.
3. Edit the applet tag on archive as  `archive = APTracker.jar, mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar`
4. Paste again the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar` to where the files like .html, .class and the like are located.

Comment: **Don't** put Jars in the `jre\lib\ext` directory (point 2)!  Add them to the run-time class-path of apps. as required.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the MySQL JDBC jar is missing.

you can download that jar from: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: I have already included the connector within my jre, jdk, and class filepath  - all of which showed no change.

Comment: Also I am fairly certain I would get a classNotFoundException if it were the JDBC jar missing, not an SQLException.

Comment: "I guess the MySQL JDBC jar is missing."  Seems that way, unless the MySQL Jar is called `APTracker.jar` (which I doubt).  Only classes in Jars mentioned in the `archive` attribute are available to an applet's run-time class-path (ignoring their existence in the extensions directory of the JRE - which really does not work for an applet).

Comment: @Andrew: the required com and org files were extracted from the JDBC jar and input into the APTracker.jar.